# PHP: Variable doesn't compare to string

Tags: php, string, simple-html-dom

I'm scraping an html page and trying to get the text value. But when I try to compare the text string, it always returns false.

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$url = "http://google.com";

$date = "date";
$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach($html->find('table.tablehead') as $table)  
  foreach($table->find('tr') as $row)
  {
    foreach($row->find('td') as $item)
    { 
      $item1 = strtolower(trim($item));

      if($item1 == $date)
        echo $item->.' ';
    } 
    echo '<br/>';
  }
?>
```

The line "if($item1 == "date")" always returns false. I've tried strcmp, regex, === and other functions.

Comment: What is the value of $item? Did you try to print it before your if clause? I don't think that it is a date string or even a string.

Comment: `$item` is a DOM object... use `$item->plaintext` to retrieve it's content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks as `Simple HTML DOM` (`file_get_html`). If necessary date in `<td>`, change line:

```
  $item1 = strtolower(trim($item));
```

To:

```
  $item1 = strtolower(trim($item->plaintext)); // return inner text from tag `<td>`
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `var_dump($item)`? Because you might find that it's a DOM element, not a string.

I don't know what DOM library you're using - I use DOMDocument myself - but you should have a `textContent` property you can use to get the element's... well, text content.

Comment: looks to be Simple HTML DOM

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Quite possibly, judging by that include filename... I should probably have said "I don't know the DOM library" :D